Как ОС загружается в ОП, если драйвер ОП загружается вместе с ОС?
Неужели все базовые возможности ОП одинаковы для любой ОП любого производителя? Иначе как без загрузки драйвера ОП, загрузчик загружает данные ОС в ОП? Если вопрос глупый, то извините.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS

Оперативная память доступна центральному процессору непосредственно, и ни в каких драйверах не нуждается.
Тем не менее, важной частью любой ОС является менеджер памяти, который выделяет память процессам, освобождает её, и, при необходимости, свопирует с постоянной памятью на диске или аналогичном устройстве.
Работу ОЗУ (ОП) на аппаратном уровне поддерживает т. н. чипсет материнской платы. И драйвер чипсета всегда используется ОС, но это связано не с ОЗУ, а с множеством других устройств в чипсете.

Не доступна (по крайней мере DDR и т.п. Статика внутри доступна, но она напрямую исполняемой в CPU программе обычно не доступна (хотя я и запускал в ней (в L3))). Перед ОС работает firmware код (начиная с кода в ROM, который стартует по ресету чипа (потом обычно с флешки на плате он грузит в статическую память firmware loader)). Именно он инициализирует DDR, а потом грузит в память с носителя самый начальный загрузчик ОС и предает ему управление. / Хотя.... Может софт, который я тут кратко описал надо рассматривать как часть аппаратуры?

@avp ЦП работает напрямую с оперативной памятью и постоянной памятью BIOS и устройств.

@avp а что будет если попытаться использоваться память до момента инициализации DRAM?

@andreymal,  Я думаю, контроллер памяти зависнет. Там сначала надо phy (цифро-аналоговая часть, приемник и передатчик для обмена с чипами DDR на плате) настроить (это называется training)

@rotabor, не все тонкости внутреннего устройства чипа принято рассказывать простому народу. Тот кто вам сказал, что напрямую, либо сам не знает как это устроено, либо сильно упрощает, дабы не смущать неокрепшие умы

@avp Это я сам сказал, я знаю это не один десяток лет. Сейчас АО компьютера гораздо сложнее, и есть и котроллер ОЗУ, и другие устройства, ответственные за работу ОЗУ, которые находятся в микросхемах чипсета. Но главное остаётся неизменным - ЦП работает с ОЗУ напрямую, читает и записывает информацию, непосредственно её адресуя.

@avp всё, о чём вы пишите, относится к аппаратному обеспечению, которое сейчас само по себе уже представляет миниатюрые компьютеры со своими программами и процессорами. Контроллер ОЗУ в микросхеме чипсета вполне может быть микропрограммным устройством, но он не является "прокладкой" между ЦП и ОЗУ, как драйверы устройств.

@rotabor, можно и так смотреть. А можно и расширить вашу точку зрения и считать ядро ОС тоже частью аппаратуры.

@avp Можно и так считать. А можно написать программу, которая будет работать на компьютере безо всякой ОС. В частности, ОС и является такой программой.

@rotabor, это верно. Как раз такие программы (функциональные тесты bare metal называются) я в основном и пишу

@avp Серьёзная работа!
